# When a Flask application with Flask-SQLAlchemy is running, how do I use MySQL client on the same database at the same time?

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

When I run a Flask application which is using Flask-SQLAlchemy, it seems that Flask-SQLAlchemy is holding a session and when I issue a MySQL command, like alter table add column, in MySQL client  terminal, the commands cannot be executed until I quit the Flask application.

Does anybody have similar experience? How can I issue commands on MySQL client without interrupting the Flask application?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to look at this question [SQL Alchemy Relationship loader leaves a lock on table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014824/sql-alchemy-relationship-loader-leaves-a-lock-on-table)

What you'll need to do is subclass [`flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy`](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy) and override the [`apply_driver_hacks`](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.apply_driver_hacks) method to pass through the additional keyword argument [`isolation_level='READ <some level>'`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/dialects/mysql.html#transaction-isolation-level):

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

class UnLockedAlchemy(SQLAlchemy):
    def apply_driver_hacks(self, app, info, options):
        if not "isolation_level" in options:
            options["isolation_level"] = "READ COMMITTED"  # For example
        return super(UnLockedAlchemy, self).apply_driver_hacks(app, info, options)
```