# How to disable SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS for a particular binding?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two bindings for my flask app. One to Hive and one to an in memory sqlite table. I have setup the bind as follows

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = config_json['flask_app_config'].get('DEV_DATABASE_URL')
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = config_json['flask_app_config'].get('SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS')
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'users': 'sqlite:///',
    'application': SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
}
```

I then refer to this bind in my models.py as follows

```
class OAuth(OAuthConsumerMixin, db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'users'
    pass
```

During runtime, I'm getting an error creating this db because of the connection arguments

```
  File "/Users/dummy/PycharmProjects/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 453, in connect
return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
       │    │     │        │        └ {'configuration': {'hive.execution.engine': 'tez', 'tez.queue.name': 'development', 'mapreduce.job.queuename': 'd...
       │    │     │        └ (':memory:',)
       │    │     └ <built-in function connect>
       │    └ <module 'sqlite3.dbapi2' from '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/sqlite...
       └ <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.pysqlite.SQLiteDialect_pysqlite object at 0x108405b70>

TypeError: 'configuration' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

How do I selectively apply the engine options to one of the bindings and not the other?

Comment: Did you figure out a work around for this?

Comment: @lv10 No, I ended up using session storage for my purpose.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I ended using overriding the overriding `apply_driver_hacks` as suggested: https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/67#issuecomment-33196525 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384323/when-a-flask-application-with-flask-sqlalchemy-is-running-how-do-i-use-mysql-cl?answertab=active#tab-top