# Flask-SqlAlchemy per Binding Engine Options

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

There seems like there should be a clean way specify engine options for a bind? Based on the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58968503/how-to-disable-sqlalchemy-engine-options-for-a-particular-binding), I am guessing not?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options but don't really care for either:

1. Use [apply_driver_hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384323/when-a-flask-application-with-flask-sqlalchemy-is-running-how-do-i-use-mysql-cl?answertab=active#tab-top) as suggested in the comments of the above link.
2. Use [SQLAlchemy event hooks](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#controlling-how-parameters-are-passed-to-the-dbapi-connect-function) to modify the connection, passing the bind engine like `db.engines['bind_name']` to the event decorator. Note: you do need to be within the application context for this to work.

I ended up using 2 because I was already comfortable with the method having used it for dynamic tokens but would really like a cleaner solution.