# how to load data into mysql database when a flask app is running and "protecting" the data?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have several flask (python=3.10)  applications running on my server (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS). They are, as of now, working great and being served via Apache and mod_wsgi. My requirements.txt is below.

For example, this is from the conf file in the sites-enabled directory:

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess opinions threads=2 user=ray python-home=/home/ray/opinions/.venv home=/home/ray/opinions/
    WSGIScriptAlias /opinions /home/ray/opinions/opinions.py
    <Directory /home/ray/opinions/>
        WSGIProcessGroup opinions
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

This app is using sqlalchemy to connect to a mysql database.

The problem is that if I want to dump into the database (with, for example, "mysqldump <db1> | mysql meetings"), I cannot do it without shutting off the flask application. AFAIK the way to do this is edit the conf file, comment out this app and restart apache. Then, after the data write, edit the conf file again, uncomment the app and restart apache again. It is a PITA to do this every time.

There are obvious reasons for flask to want to protect the data, but I want to be able to turn off this safety feature. I cannot just take the lock statements out of the SQL that is writing the data. That does not work.

Do I need to change something in my flask setup, my setup of the sqlalchemy connection, the mod_wsgi setup, or what? Any suggestions appreciated.

I see [When a Flask application with Flask-SQLAlchemy is running, how do I use MySQL client on the same database at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384323/when-a-flask-application-with-flask-sqlalchemy-is-running-how-do-i-use-mysql-cl) but wow that looks hack-ish. And old. Is this still the way?

```
$ cat requirements.txt
click==8.1.3
Flask==2.2.2
greenlet==2.0.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
PyMySQL==1.0.2
python-dotenv==0.21.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.42
Werkzeug==2.2.2
```

Comment: Can you try running the dump in a transaction and skipping the default table locking behavior as [described here](https://mysqldump.guru/run-mysqldump-without-locking-the-tables.html)?

Comment: Nope. I did the mysqldump with --skip-lock-tables and it made no difference. I still cannot load the data without stopping the app.

Comment: Did you also wrap it in a transaction?

Comment: Hm. I am not sure why I would need to. But I will try that also.

Comment: Adding the transaction to the mysqldump does not help.